# Density of given Uniform iid Sample

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function

Assume a pure random sample ${X_1},{X_2},...,{X_n}$ is given from a
 uniform distribution on the interval $\left[ {0,\theta } \right]$ with
 $\theta $ the unknown model parameter. Hence, the density function
 ${f_x}$ of $X$ is given by ${f_x} = {1 \over \theta }$, with
 $0 < x < \theta $. Consider ${\rm{maximu}}{{\rm{m}}_{i = 1,...,n}}{X_i} =
 {X_{\left( n \right)}}$.

Show that the density of $Y = {{{X_{\left( n \right)}}} \over \theta
 }$ is given by ${f_y} = n{u^{n - 1}}$, with $0 < u < 1$

---

Please bear in mind I don't have a strong math background. My attempt went like this:

If ${f_x} = {1 \over \theta }$, then the cdf is given by $${F_x} = \int\limits_0^x {{1 \over \theta }dt}  = {x \over \theta }$$
Since it's an iid sample, the joint cdf of maximum $X$ would be something like $${F_{{x_{\left( n \right)}}}} = {\left( {{x \over \theta }} \right)^n}$$
Then $$Y = {{{X_{\left( n \right)}}} \over \theta } = {{{{\left( {{x \over \theta }} \right)}^n}} \over \theta } = {{{x^n}} \over {{\theta ^{n + 1}}}}$$
Which means
$${f_y} = {d \over {dx}}Y = {1 \over {{\theta ^{n + 1}}}}n{x^{n - 1}}$$

From where I can't progress. Not sure about my steps until then either.

Comment: Not sure either if the $u$ factor is more relevant than I'm currently thinking. Never seen it in similar questions.

Comment: Notations are messed up. You are supposed to find the cdf of $Y$ and differentiate that to get the pdf.

Comment: I thought I had done that in this part: $Y = {{{X_{\left( n \right)}}} \over \theta } = {{{{\left( {{x \over \theta }} \right)}^n}} \over \theta } = {{{x^n}} \over {{\theta ^{n + 1}}}}$
By dividing $X's$ Cdf like that I don't get to $Y's$ Cdf?

Comment: That part is meaningless; cdf is $P(Y\le y)=P(X_{(n)}/\theta\le y)=\cdots$

Comment: Thank you, I got it with your correction.